# Closure properties between 2 languages of different types

Tags: formal-languages, automata, context-free-grammar, regular-language

Whenever said - The intersection between a Context Free Language and a Regular Language is always Context Free, what is the best logical way to confirm the statement?
I have [this](http://ccl.pku.edu.cn/doubtfire/Syntax/Introduction/Chomsky/Chomsky_Hierarchy/Chapter%2024%20The%20Chomsky%20Hierarchy.files/ch24_0.jpg) Chomsky hierarchy in mind that I refer whenever closure properties between **Type-m** and **Type-n** languages are asked but sometimes I come up with a wrong result.
How do you people logically solve it? What is the best simplest way?

Answer (score 0):

To prove closure there are several types of arguments. For example you can show that there is an algorithmic way to form a grammar of type-m for the intersection of a type-m with an type-n language (which works for the context free and regular case). Another way is to use the machine characterisation of a class of languages (i.e. construct a push down automaton that accepts the intersection in the context-free with regular case). To show the intersection is not always of a certain type you can use the different pumping lemmata (or Myhill-Moore theorem in the regular case) with a particular example.

You see this is a very general answer, however if you are looking for a specific case, tell us and I can try to answer more specifically to the setting in question.